# How to solve error Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, overflow

When running the following query(I created the query using python):

```
SELECT x, y, z, sum(r) AS R 
FROM data_table 
WHERE [start_time] >= convert(datetime, '2022-02-03') 
  AND [end_time] <= CONVERT(datetime, '2022-02-07')
GROUP BY x, y, z
```

I got the error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

If I change the date to '2022-02-04' it is working fine.
Can someone help me fix my query that it will work in all dates?

Comment: You need to show your table structure and provide sample data that reproduces the error. Most likely your column `R` is too small to handle the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like the result of `sum()` overflows, how about cast the r to `bigint`
before sum the result up :

```
SELECT x, y, z, sum(cast(r as bigint)) AS R 
FROM data_table 
WHERE [start_time] >= convert(datetime, '2022-02-03') 
  AND [end_time] <= CONVERT(datetime, '2022-02-07')
GROUP BY x, y, z
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=92bb09feda97b1fe8d20d62d4465b13f)*